# Телеграм Бот Java (Приветственное сообщение для нового пользователя)

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Помогите с реализацией.

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update u) {

List<User> users = u.getMessage().getNewChatMembers();
   
 String userName = new User().getFirstName();

if (users.add(new User())) {
    sendMsg(u.getMessage().getChatId().toString(), "Добро пожаловать " + userName);
}
```

написал такую ересь. как то работает

когда добавляет пользователя, пишет:

> Добро пожаловать null

И все остальные методы не работают. В консоле такой текст при попытки использовать другие команды:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:39)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1378)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:306)
```

Помогите с реализацией данной задумки (а именно - когда добавляется новый пользователь в группу (неважно каким путём (добавили/перешел по ссылке) его встречал бы текст, с его именем пользователя)

Comment: А у тебя есть полный код проекта приветствия? Можешь дать?

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто. У юзера может не быть юзернейма, соответственно чтобы избежать исключительных ситуаций и `null` вместо имени, следует

```
"Добро пожаловать " + userName
```

переписать как

```
"Добро пожаловать " + (userName == null ? user.FirstName : username)
```